# Why is the application not starting from top

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have created iphone game.When i pause the game using pause button i quit cliking quit button...

Now when i start the game again ..the  previous counter i created using this code...

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerFunc) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

the timer is 100 sec and moves to zero...now it start giving the difference of twwo ,,98,96,94

if i quit the game again ans start this time the difference will become of 4 96,92 ...its keep on increasing ....what is this issue?

kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like "multi-tasking" and improperly placed initialization code.

You may not actually be "exiting" your application when you think you are.  Double check that the application is not still running in the background after you press the "home" button.

Also, it could have something to do with your "quit" button as well - where it is not actually "quitting" but rather putting the application into the background?